# kafka consumer in java not responding

Tags: apache-kafka

i am trying to run this KAFKA consumer code in java for a particular topic but its not receiving any message from that topic. Server in running on a different windows machine. please help me out.

```
{Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.100.144.157:2181");
     props.put("group.id", "test");
     props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
     props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
     props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
     props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
     consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test"));
     final int minBatchSize = 200;
     List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
     while (true) {
         ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
             buffer.add(record);
         }
         if (buffer.size() >= minBatchSize) {
             insertIntoDb(buffer);
             consumer.commitSync();
             buffer.clear();
         }
     }}
```

Comment: Can you run `kafka-console-consumer.bat` and verify that you can receive messages on your client machine?

Comment: from console i am getting the message on client machine. In java thread is running but i am not receiving any message.

Comment: With the consumer running, add another message to the topic and see if the consumer sees it.  The consumer may have initialized its offset to the most recent available offset.

Comment: You could also try setting `auto.offset.reset` to either `earliest` or `smallest` (depending on the versions of things). That way you'd start out reading the topic from the beginning rather than the end.

Comment: with the consumer running i have send a message from producer and consumer received the message. @Chris Gerken

Comment: I have tried with this setting also  (auto.offset.reset) . But its not working.

Comment: In zookeeper console I am getting this exception repeatedly when I am running this java consumer code.
**Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException**